# Inner class and this() constructor

Tags: java, constructor, this, inner-classes

I have 2 classes: Date and Person
Person has two attributes of Date class

Case 1

`Date` class is separate class from Person class. I have this piece of code working properly:

```
private String name;
private Date born;
private Date died; // null indicates still alive.

public Person(String initialName, int birthMonth, int birthDay, 
      int birthYear) {
   // requirement from the instructor:
   // **implement using the this() constructor**
    this(initialName, new Date(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear), null);
}
```

Case 2: Inner class (an assignment requirement)

I put the `Date` as the private inner class of `Person`

Now the above constructor code does not work anymore.
Here is the error message:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   No enclosing instance of type Person is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation   Person.java /Wk03_Ch10_FileIO_Ch13_Interfaces/wk03_Ch10_FileIO_Ch13_Inner_Classes   line 43 Java Problem`

How do I solve the problem? I can do this:

```
Date dt = new Date(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
```

Unfortunately `this()` has to be the first line in the constructor

Another work around is

```
public Person(String initialName, int birthMonth, int birthDay, 
      int birthYear) {
   // implement using the this() constructor
    this.name = initialName;
    this.born = new Date(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
    this.died = null;
}
```

However the last piece of code does not satisfy my instructor requirement of using `this()` method inside the constructor.

Comment: No. I am supposed to use private inner class (I think)

Comment: @BevynQ I tried to make Date private static inner class and my original code works. So I will ask the instructor if that is acceptable. Meanwhile, any other way? Thanks

Comment: Your instructor needs to be clear about terminology.  From the [Official Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html): Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.  Generally speaking a _nested static class_ is not an _inner class_.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create inner member (non-`static`) classes within a call to another constructor. From [JLS §8.8.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1):

> **An explicit constructor invocation statement in a constructor body** (sic: the call to `this()`) **may not refer to any** instance variables or instance methods or **inner classes declared in this class or any superclass**, or use `this` or `super` in any expression; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

The reason is that non-`static` inner classes may require access to the class while it's being constructed. For example:

```
public class OuterClass {

    private String name;
    private InnerClass inner;

    public OuterClass(String name, InnerClass inner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public OuterClass(String name) {
        this(name, new InnerClass()); // Will not compile
    }

    public class InnerClass {

        public InnerClass() {
            // Access to name is allowed since this inner class isn't static
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

The major problem here is that when we construct the non-`static` inner class, it can access non-`static` members from its enclosing instance (the `OuterClass`, but the enclosing `OuterClass` hasn't yet made its call to `super()` and is therefore considered unsafe to access. In fact, if that code was allowed to compile, it would print `null` due to constructor invocation order. In short, the `InnerClass` would be created before the call to `this.name = name`, a similar concept to the information presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors).

The solution is to make `InnerClass` a `static` inner class and pass the name to it directly:

```
public class OuterClass {

    private String name;
    private InnerClass inner;

    public OuterClass(String name, InnerClass inner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public OuterClass(String name) {
        this(name, new InnerClass(name));
    }

    public static class InnerClass {

        public InnerClass(String name) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

`InnerClass` cannot access `name` from the `OuterClass` once it's declared `static`, so we have to pass it explicitly on construction now, but this is better since the initial code would have been broken anyway.

**Edit:**

Per your question:

> What confused me is that I can create an object of a `Date` type in the `Person`'s constructor, as long as it is not inside the `this()` method. I can do this: `Date dt = new Date(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);` What is the difference between the above and `this(...., new Date(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear), ...)`?

The difference is that in the call outside of `this()`, all the calls to `super()` have taken place, they take place as part of `this()` because of implicit calls to `super()`, so the object has reached a point where it is considered okay to be accessed. Your `Date` instance can't access the `Person` class because there is no context for the `Person` and its fields yet, so the compiler doesn't allow it.

In short, once `this()` has been called, then at least the calls to `super()` have happened, which is the driving force behind this constraint, and also why overridable method calls are discouraged. If a method is overridden by a subclass and then called in the superclass' constructor, fields from the subclass can be accessed before the subclass has even been initialized, even resulting in `null` being returned for `final` fields. **Basically, it's all about protecting yourself from accessing your class before a call to `super()` has been invoked.**

Comment: What confused me is that I can create an object of a Date type in the Person's constructor, as long as it is not inside the this() method. I can do this: `Date dt = new Date(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);` What is the difference between the above and `this(...., new Date(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear), ...)`?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am sorry that I can not vote up your answer, yet.

Answer (score 0):

While I would never create a `Date` class inside of a `Person` class (sounds like a bad idea from an application-modeling perspective!), you seem to have said that it is a requirement in some assignment.

If you are set up like this:

```
public class Person {

    ...

    class Date {
        ...
    }

}
```

Then inside methods of `Person`, you will need to invoke the `Date` constructor with:

```
this.new Date(...)
```

That is the syntax Java uses.  You need an enclosing instance of type Person on which to create objects of the inner class.  The thing about inner classes (whether they are member, local, or anonymous) is that each instance exists bound to an instance of the outer class.  So if I had a person instance `p`, I could say:

```
p.new Date(...)
```

The big problem here though is that you cannot create dates in the `Person` constructor that use the about-to-be-created person!  For example, this [fails](http://ideone.com/uYanjW):

```
public Person() {
    this(this.new Date());
}
```

because the value of `this` isn't ready for use in this way yet (although interestingly, you can sometimes use `this` inside constructors in other cases, such as storing it in arrays, for example).

Like you realized, making `Date` a *static nested class* is fine, because instances of static nested classes are not tied to any instances of the enclosing class, so this is the best solution.  If you really have to have an inner class, you're not going to be able to pass a new date as an "argument" of a `this()` expression and have it bound to the person you are creating!  Maybe that is the point of the assignment (is this a graduate class? :-))

Comment: In theory, you're right. But, tested on ideone ([code example](http://ideone.com/HFIxVL)) and doesn't work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza +1 Nice, thanks! I was just trying this, too. +1 for getting to it first.  Makes sense because the enclosing instance doesn't exist until the person constructor is done.  The whole "assignment" is very suspicious.  Might be a misunderstanding? :)

Comment: Here is the error message:Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor Person.java /Wk03_Ch10_FileIO_Ch13_Interfaces/wk03_Ch10_FileIO_Ch13_Inner_Classes line 43 Java Problem

Comment: This can be easily solved by marking the inner class as `static`. But, if teacher doesn't want students use `static` inner class (since it is not a real inner class) then the best bet would be passing a `null` argument to the constructor and then setting the `birthDay` after calling the constructor.

Comment: First help, how to do a new line in the comment? and How to make a section of code, like the original posting? Sorry, a newbie here

Comment: @Ray Toal: It could be my misunderstanding. Sending couple of emails already, so I guess, we just need to wait the answers. I was being super careful as my first assignment got a lot of points deducted by not following the teacher's wishes to the dot :-) My program worked and I still got a 'C'. OTH, the teacher lamented that half of the class failed. A tough grader I have in my hand ;)

Comment: I hope you find out what you need.  I edited my answer based on Luiggi's excellent comments.  I think that either (1) the static nested class is desired and the assignment was just worded in a confusing manner, or (2) you got a trick question!!, or (3) the professor assigned something without thinking through the ramifications of the problem.  Hope you get this.  Good question BTW.

Comment: Thanks Ray also everybody else who answered. No answer from the instructor yet. Nope, not a graduate class, it is only 200 level class! That is why I was surprised by the level of the assignment and the toughness of the grading! My assignment #2 was to create a simulated world of Ant and Bug (moving, breeding, eating, starving)!